# get content itemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridInboxMessage" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="title" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Title" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Body" SortExpression="Body">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="MyBody" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# TruncateText(Eval("Body"))%>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sender">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="MySender" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# GetSenderNameFromID(Eval("Sender"))%>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="MyDate" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date1", "{0:MMMM d yyy}")%>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<div id="FullBody"></div>
```

Code Behind

```
protected string TruncateText(object objBody)
{
    string truncated = "";
    if (objBody != null)
    {
        truncated = objBody.ToString().Length > 50 ? 
            objBody.ToString().Substring(0, 47) + "..." : objBody.ToString();
    }
    return truncated;
}
```

1.I want that in

```
protected void gridInboxMessage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = gridInboxMessage.SelectedRow;
    //i want show full body in div `fullBody`
}
```

how can access to body to show full body in div `fullBody`

2.I want even rows with background color is black?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access `div` from your code behind, the easiest way is to set `runat` property of your div to `true` i.e. `<div id="fullbody" runat="server"/>`

Then in your code behind, you can access it just like anyother control: `fullbody.some_property = "";`

And for alternative row background color you can use: `<alternatingrowstyle backcolor="Black" />`